# Play mp3 on raspberry with mpg123 and c++

Tags: c++, mp3, raspberry-pi

I want to use the following example program: http://hzqtc.github.io/2012/05/play-mp3-with-libmpg123-and-libao.html it uses

```
#include <ao/ao.h> 
#include <mpg123.h>
```

I installed libao-dev and mpg123 with

```
sudo apt-get install libao-dev
sudo apt-get install mpg123
```

and then build the file with

```
gcc -O2 -o play play.c -lmpg123 -lao
```

I get the following error

```
"fatal error: mpg123.h no such file or directory".
```

Do I need to install another mpg123 development package or build the package myself from source on the raspberry to get a working library? Or what do I need to include, to get g++ find the mpg123 library? Libao library seems to be found...
Playing an mp3 file using "mpg123 text.pm3" works. But I searched the complete file structure for "mpg123.h" but the file doesn't exist. So I assume I need some additional program to be installed that includes the library, can anyone help me which one it is? Or is only option to build mpg123 from source?

Thanks for any help :-)!

Comment: locate mpg123.h gives something ?

Comment: locate leads to "command not found". But I used "sudo find -name 'mpg123.h'" starting from base directory / and no file was found. So I think it does not exist. When I did the same for "ao.h", it returned the file ./usr/include/ao/ao.h

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You probably missing to install the dev package associated to libmpg123

```
sudo apt-get install libmpg123-dev
```

[Useful feature]

If you search a package with APT used

```
sudo apt-cache search [package]
```

For example with mpg123 you can found easily the development package ;)

Comment: Is there a way to figure out which package needs to be installed? I tryed mpg123-dev, but this doesn't exist. Is it always the name lib+package+-dev?

Comment: yes because you try to compile with -lmpg123, it's refered to library and it's always something like libpackage-dev, if u search a package with apt u can do sudo apt-cache search package ;) (-dev is necessary if you need header file of library)

Comment: Hi, I followed the question and answer here and when I use "./play.c /home/pi/CH.mp3" I get no sound at all. I checked the analog port with earphones and youtube on pi and it was ok. Can that be because there is no mp3 player installed on the pi ?